# Stroke order of kana (not kanji)

Tags: katakana, hiragana, kana, handwriting, stroke-order

I have learned hiragana and katakana, but the book I have learned these from alas does not show their stroke order. I have the Takoboto dictionary fire Android smartphones installed, which displays kanji stroke order very clearly, but not for kana.what is a good app or online resource that displays the stroke order for kana (preferably clearly, and allowing me to go through all kana quickly)?

Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Stroke_order) [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Stroke_order_and_direction).

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Obenkyo&hl=en

Comment: here you go ! http://drawmeakanji.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, the stroke order is quite natural and follows the same logic as kanji(top-left toward bottom-right).
Since most kana only have about 1 or 2 strokes(although mostly written in 1 stoke by natives trying to write really fast), it hardly gets confusing as long as you stick with that rule.
For more detailed info you should check the links some sent to you in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a post about it:
http://hcm9999.blogspot.jp/2013/12/hiragana-katakana.html

Download the PDF files. They have the stroke orders for all kanas.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you intend to use Japanese. I learned Kana through memrise very quickly (a couple of weeks). This was great to recognise and *to read* the characters on a computer screen. This is handy to read printed text, food packets, train station signs, etc.

However, I didn't take much care with the stroke order until I began learning Kanji and some habits are tough to break. As with Kanji the handwritten forms can be difficult to read if written incorrectly, particularly in cursive. It's good to be familiar with cursive Kana as they are used in different fonts. The *Aedict and

Notably the hiragana さ, き, and ふ are often stylised differently. Similarly, the katakana ソ, ン, シ, and ツ are very difficult to distinguish without practice writing them in the correct order.

Many Japanese learning Apps or texts will guide you with the correct order while learning *to write* Kana. The **Aedict** and **Kanji Study** Apps both support stroke order for Kana.